# Where can I find a reliable source for the U.S. national population estimated since 1790?

Tags: united-states, population, reference

I am shocked that I cannot put my finger on this information and I must resort to asking here. I am looking for U.S. population estimates from 1790-present. Preferably there is an estimate for each year, but I am ok with just the census values every 10 years. I have tried navigating the U.S. Census Bureau's website for at least an hour with unsatisfactory results.

I have also found [this](http://www.u-s-history.com/pages/h980.html) website, but I am looking for something which looks more citable.

Answer (score 5):

You can read PDFs of all US censuses since 1790 on the [US Census website](https://www.census.gov/prod/www/decennial.html).

If the PDF's are a problem, Wikipedia keeps pages for all of them too, with nice modern HTML graphs rather than scans. Here's [the one for 1790](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1790_United_States_Census). The grand total was a bit under 4 Million.